# How do get linebreaks from Lua source files

Tags: luatex, strings

I'm creating documents in LuaTeX from Lua sources containing long multiline strings (`[=[ string ]=]`). When I print the strings using `tex.print`, LuaTeX "eats up" line breaks. For instance, I have the string

```lua
A = [=[
Here we go.
Text. More text.
And more text to go.
]=]
```

but `tex.print` outputs

```
Here we go. Text. More text. And more text to go.
```

This doesn't happen in Lua, but it does in LuaTeX. Is there a way to fix that? Consider a large amount of multiline strings, so editing strings manually is not a possibility for me.

Comment: `tex.print` generates a sequence of tokens, no string with `\n`. TeX manipulates with sequences of tokens only, no strings. So use something different than TeX if you need to manipulate with strings.

Comment: the tex.print outputs the lines but the effect is the same as newlines in a normal tex source file. they render as spaces by default try `\obeylines`

Comment: \obeylines does not work as I expected, but it makes some work. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ConTeXt, you can use (in a standalone [CLD](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/CLD) document):

```
local A = [=[
Here we go.
Text. More text.
And more text to go.
]=]

context.starttext()
context.startlines()
context(A)
context.stoplines()
context.stoptext()
```

or in a regular TeX document:

```
\startluacode
    local A = [=[
    Here we go.
    Text. More text.
    And more text to go.
    ]=]
\stopluacode

\starttext
\startluacode
    context.startlines()
    context(A)
    context.stoplines()
\stopluacode
\stoptext
```

Not sure what is the equivalent to `\startlines ... \stoplines` in LaTeX, but that should work in LaTeX as well.

Answer (score 3):

You have to split the string into lines at the `\n` and then use `tex.print` (not `tex.sprint`) to print them, because this will insert the end-of-line marker that is needed by `\obeylines`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode*}
A = [=[
Here we go.
Text. More text.
And more text to go.
]=]
\end{luacode*}

\begin{document}

{\obeylines\directlua{
    for _, line in ipairs(string.splitlines(A)) do
        tex.print(line)
    end
}}

\end{document}
```